# IBM Watson Assistnat: Extend the Webhook's time when sending a webhook to a Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

While developing a client application that uses its own styling, but also `IBM Watson Assistant` under the hood, problems have been discovered when the webhook's time is exceeded. The composition is as follows: a client app sends a request to `Watson Assistant`, from there the Assistant triggers a `webhook`, which after that triggers an `IBM Cloud Function`.

Following this [link](https://github.com/ibm-cloud-docs/assistant/blob/master/faqs.md), a man can see that in one of the FAQs is stated, that the time limit (*8 seconds*) can not be extended. Does it include also the case when a call is made to a `IBM Cloud Function`?

Update:

```
async function main(){
    try {
        const orders = await db.getOrders();
        if(orders.quantity > 0){
            return {data: 'there are some orders'};
        } else {
            return {data: 'there are no orders'};
        }
    } catch(err) {
        return {error: err.message};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if you are already doing this, but why not return a promise from your cloud function. That way the return is almost immediate falling within your 8 seconds, but the processing would become asynchronous.

eg.

```js
function main (args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I've updated the original question. By doing so, is it considered as a valid approach in terms of the Webhook?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct the 8 seconds limit is still in effect. It will most likely change in the future